# C extract an array from a matrix using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix, indexing

I wrote a code and I have some data stored in a 2d matrix:

```
 double y[LENGTH][2];
```

I have a function that take as input a 1D array:

```
 double function(double* data)
```

I am interested in passing the data stored in the first column of this matrix to this function. How can I do that using pointers?
My function is something like (where the array data is an array of double containing LENGTH elements:

```
double data[LENGTH];
```

):

```
double function(double* data){
     double result=0;
     for(int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++){    
         result+=data[i];
     }
     return result;
}
```

And I want to pass to this function a row of a matrix as data input.

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: can you show some code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: can you include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)/[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that states what your problem is?

Comment: My problem is that I do not know ho to point to the first column of a matrix as an array and if it is possible

Comment: please read the: http://pdf.sibooksan.com/fldr_mar10/kernighan_ritchie_c.pdf where this is all explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass a pointer to the first element of your 2D matrix, you can access it as a 1 D matrix since the elements are stored contiguously:

```
double y[LENGTH][2];
x = function(y[0]);
...
double function(double* p) {
  int ii;
  double sum=0;
  for(ii=0; ii<2*LENGTH; ii++) sum += p[ii];
  return sum;
}
```

Note that in this case the order of accessing the elements is

```
y[0][0]
y[0][1]
y[1][0]
y[1][1]
y[2][0]
... etc
```

**update** - you just clarified your question a little bit. If you want to access just one column of data, you need to skip through the array. This means you need to know the size of the second dimension. I would recommend something like this:

```
double function(double* p, int D2) {
  int ii;
  double sum=0;
  for(ii=0; ii<D2*LENGTH; ii+=D2) sum += p[ii];
  return sum;
}
```

And you would call it with

```
x = function(y[colNum], numCols);
```

Now we start at a certain location, then, skip forward `D2` elements to access the next element in the column.

I have to say that this is rather ugly - this is not really how C is intended to be used. I would recommend wrapping things into a class that handles these things for you cleanly - in other words, switch to C++ (although it's possible to write pure C functions that "hide" some of this complexity). You could of course copy the data to another memory block to make it contiguous, but that's usually considered a last recourse.

Be careful that you don't end up with code that is unreadable / unmaintainable...

**further update**

Per your comment, the above is still not what you wanted. Then I recommend the following:

```
double *colPointer(double *p, int rowCount, int colCount) {
  double *cp;
  int ii;
  cp = malloc(rowCount * sizeof *cp);
  for(ii=0; ii<rowCount; ii++) cp[ii] = *(p + ii * colCount);
  return cp;
}
```

This will return a pointer to a newly created copy of the column. You call it with

```
double *cc;
cc = colPointer(y[colNum], LENGTH, 2);
answer = function(cc);
```

And now you can use `cc` in the way you wanted. If you have to do this many times you might be **better off transposing the entire array just once** - that way you can pass a pointer to a row of the transpose and achieve your result. You can adapt the code above to generate such a transpose.

Note that there is a risk of memory leaks if you don't clean up after yourself with this method.

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I meant. See my edits

Answer (score 0):

the question is that do you consider to be the row-dimension.
usually the first one is rows and the second one cols.
that means that your `double y[LENGTH][2];` is a matrix with `LENGTH` rows ans 2 cols.

if that is also your interpretation then the answer to your question is "you can't" since the memory is layed out like this:

```
r0c0 r0c1 r1c0 r1c1 r2c0 r2c1 ...
```

you can retrieve pointer to a row but not to a column.

matrix classes are usually designed in a way, that row and column step length is stored so that by carefully setting them you can build sub matrices on a big data chunk.

you may look for opencv matrix implementation if you plan to perform complexer tasks.

if you can change the implementation of the function you want to call. you can change it to accept the row step (number of your columns), so that it does not joust increment the pointer by one to reach the next element but to increment the pointer by row step.

as an alternative there is the obvious way to copy the required column to a new array.

edit:
fixed stupid error on memory layout diagram